# Where do I find the solver error code definitions for Coin-OR CBC that Pyomo returns?

Tags: python, pyomo, coin-or-cbc, coin-or

I see `ERROR: - Solver (cbc) returned non-zero return code (-9)` when running my Pyomo problem.

I have tried `solve(instance, tee=True, keepfiles=True, logfile="my.log")` but the `my.log` is not appearing.  I have searched through the Pyomo and cbc github repositories but I do not understand how to trace the error codes.

Comment: My error ended up being a OOM killer but I discovered it independently of the error code.